# Maven gives error when trying to deploy tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I have read answers related to this on stackoverflow, but still I am having this issue.

my tomcat-users.xml :

```
    <role rolename = "manager-gui" /> 
    <role rolename = "manager-script" /> 
    <user username = "AppManager"password ="password"roles ="manager-gui"/> 
    <user username = "tomcatmvn" password = "password" roles = "manager-script" />
```

pom.xml:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/myproject</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

settings.xml

```
    <server> 
       <id>TomcatServer</id> 
       <username>tomcatmvn</username> 
       <password>password</password> 
    </server>
```

When i use following: mvn -X tomcat7:deploy
I get the following error:

```
Tomcat return http status error: 403, Reason Phrase: Forbidden: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47</h3></body></html>
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Tomcat return http status error: 403, Reason Phrase: Forbidden: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report

## HTTP Status 403 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractTomcat7Mojo.checkTomcatResponse(AbstractTomcat7Mojo.java:76)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:88)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
File **`pom.xml`**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <server>localhost</server>
      <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

File **`~/.m2/settings.xml`**

```
<servers>
     <server>
         <id>localhost</id>
         <username>tomcatmvn</username>
         <password>password</password>
     </server>
</servers>
```

File **`tomcat-users.xml`**

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcatmvn" password="password" roles="manager-script"/>
```

After changing `tomcat-users.xml` restart the server. You shouldn't assign the `manager-gui` role with the `manager-script` to the same user.

Read more: [Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/) offical document and this [tutorial](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/).

Answer (score 0):

try to remove current tomcat server folder and create new one. It works well for me :D

Answer (score 0):

should add admin-gui and try start cmd using administrator privilege